# (Java) Why a superclass can have subclass-type variables?

Tags: java, oop

I saw this code in Cracking the coding Interview

```java
abstract class Entry {
    protected Directory parent;
    protected long created, lastUpdated, lastAccessed;
    protected String name;

    public Entry(String n, Directory p) {
        this.name = n;
        this.parent = p;
        created = System.currentTimeMillis();
        lastUpdated = System.currentTimeMillis();
        lastAccessed = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    ...
}

class Directory extends Entry {
    ...
}
```

If Directory inherits from Entry, why can 'Entry' have a 'Directory-type' variable? I don't understand, for me, it was just like 'chicken-and-egg' situation. Could someone explain it? Many thanks!

Comment: You should examine why you think that you can't have that. It is clear that it is possible and allowed, so somewhere in your assumption that this shouldn't be possible, there is a mistake.

Comment: @Erwin Is that not their question though? They seem to realize they've made a mistake and would like an explanation regarding _why_ they were wrong (i.e. what the mistake was).

Comment: @Slaw without knowing the OP's assumption why they don't understand or why they think this is a "chicken and egg" situation, it's a stab in the dark - it's impossible to answer this question. There could be a million reasons why they think it is strange. And by thinking why they make this assumption, they can possibly solve the question themselves.

Comment: @Erwin Due to the use of the "chicken and egg" phrase I assume their issue is thinking a parent class can't possibly know about a child class because the child class needs the parent class in order to exist. In other words, they expected a kind of "forward reference" error. But I guess your right, there could be some other reason they think it's strange.

Comment: Not all `Entry` have a parent

Comment: @Slaw Thank you! Your comment is exactly what I want to ask.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't really a problem.  When you think about it, it's no different than a 
`structure in C` which contains other structures of itself or in the following example.

```java
class Node {
   Node left;
   Node right;
}
```

The fact that there appears to be a `circular reference` in the example you cited is just an illusion.

```java
class A {
   public B b_obj
   public int n;
   public int r;
}

class B extends A {
   public in q;
}

So B has access to the following fields.
    B b_obj
    int n
    int r
    int q
```

But like all class relationships, if you assign an instance of B to variable of type A, then q will not be available.  But A can always access elements of B via it's B object, if one has been assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate the `parent` object as an instance of `Entry` class. And as such there is no reason as to why a parent type instance cannot be let inside as a field in the child class.
Also, what if the parent can be an interface and that interface is implemented by another class which has in inheritance relation with your current class?
Like this:

```
    interface Directory {

    }

    abstract class Entry {
        protected Directory directory;
    }

    class Folder implements Directory {

    }
```

As such, it doesn't make sense to disallow a parent instance as a field in the child class. Look into Run-time polymorphism as well.

Answer (score -1):

Language or OOP concept does not stop anyone write any structure of the code wether good or bad.